# Creating annotation constants for use as function return types in Android similar to Google Play Billing

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, in-app-purchase, google-play-billing

I have an Android app (written in Kotlin) for my company that we are currently adding in-app billing to in order to comply with the new rules. We also have an iOS and web app that work with the same data, so we need to validate all purchases on the backend to keep all three platforms in check. I've come across something interesting while implementing the Google Play Billing library, and I can't quite seem to figure out what exactly is happening.

As I just mentioned, we have to send all purchases to our servers to validate the purchase and update the synced database. I'm doing this using Retrofit, two custom data classes to represent a request and a response, and the Gson converter. The [recommended structure](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#process) for this is as follows:

```
fun handlePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
    if (purchase.purchaseState === PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
            // Retrofit call in the viewModel
        }
     }
}
```

When I looked at the [reference documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase.PurchaseState), Purchase.PurchaseState is listed as an annotation. I've never seen an annotation used in comparison statements before, and purchase.[purchaseState](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase#getpurchasestate) actually returns an int. When I viewed the decompiled class file in Android Studio, I received the following Java code:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface PurchaseState {
    int UNSPECIFIED_STATE = 0;
    int PURCHASED = 1;
    int PENDING = 2;
}
```

Doing some digging led me to [Typedef annotations](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations#enum-annotations). This was new to me, so I tried toying around with our custom response class to see if I could get the annotation to work in the same way as the Purchase.PurchaseState, namely so I can use it in comparison statements to display the correct message once I receive the response from the server:

```
viewModel.response.observe(this, {
    Log.i(TAG,"Acked: ${it.acknowledged}. Code: ${it.responseCode}")
    if(it.responseCode == AcknowledgementResponse.ResponseCode.OK) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Success")
    }
})
```

The closest I've been able to get is the following definition, which allows me to access the inner annotation but doesn't provide access to the values:

```
data class AcknowledgementResponse(val acknowledged: Boolean, @ResponseCode val responseCode: Int) {

    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
    @IntDef(OK, ALREADY_EXISTS, INVALID_PURCHASE, INVALID_TOKEN, ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_ERROR)
    annotation class ResponseCode

    companion object {
        const val OK = 1;
        const val ALREADY_EXISTS = 2;
        const val INVALID_PURCHASE = 3;
        const val INVALID_TOKEN = 4;
        const val ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_ERROR = 5;
    }
}
```

My current assumption is that the issue stems from incorrect placement of the annotation, the constants, or both. Any guidance and/or suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: I've spent the last several hours looking through the developer documentation for both the Kotlin and Java androidx packages, and it looks like this is not a pattern used often. In fact, I couldn't find another library that used it. Instead, it looks like it's the best choice to use enums for the comparison.
That being said, I've ready strongly conflicting opinions over the past few days about enums, with the majority saying not to use it and to use these typedef/enumerated annotations instead. I'm using Google Play Billing v3, so it is newer. Any guidance?

Comment: These typedefs are used by android because serializing enums is (was) hard and ints are easy. You should use an enum. I haven't used Gson but enums are very easy with ktor.

Comment: @Hack5 thanks for the suggestion! I haven't used ktor and am really only using Gson because that seems to be one of the easy defaults with Retrofit. I'll check it out and update with any results I find!

Comment: @Hack5 I ended up using enums and changing from Gson to Moshi, which worked in the end and passed review. I would still love to know about how typedefs work, but enums fixed my immediate issue. Thanks for the advice!